# datagrid autogeneratecolums false shows empty column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridAnagrafiche" EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding listAnagrafiche, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="rowAnagrafiche_DoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codice" Binding="{Binding cod}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gruppo" Binding="{Binding gruppo}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ragione Sociale" Binding="{Binding nome}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Indirizzo" Binding="{Binding indirizzo}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cap" Binding="{Binding cap}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Città" Binding="{Binding citta}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefono" Binding="{Binding telefono}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cellulare" Binding="{Binding cellulare}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding email}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codice Fiscale" Binding="{Binding codiceFiscale}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Partita IVA" Binding="{Binding partitaIva}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IBAN" Binding="{Binding iban}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="BIC" Binding="{Binding bic}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I would remove the empty column and not adapt last colum size with width="*"

I tried also with EnableRowVirtualization="False" but doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean the empty space after the last column?  If so, set the width of one of your DataGridTextColumns to * to take up the excess space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly you could set the HorizontalAlignment property of the DataGrid to Left in order to prevent it from stretching to fit the available width:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridAnagrafiche" EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding listAnagrafiche, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
...
```

This should effectively make the last empty column disappear.

Comment: It works but shows double border on last colum

screenshot -> https://postimg.org/image/xvylqmofz/